# Transformar coluna com data em português para o formato Date [R]

Tags: r, data, dataframe

Importei a tabela (nome dados) com as seguintes características e dados

```
data(character)       obs (numeric)
1 de Jan de 2018 00:00    0
1 de Jan de 2018 00:15    0
1 de Jan de 2018 00:30    1
1 de Jan de 2018 00:45    1
1 de Jan de 2018 01:00    2
1 de Jan de 2018 01:15    3

## O horário do campo data está no formato character, escrito em português abreviado e o intervalo de horas vai de 00:00 à 23:45
```

Quero mudar o formato da primeira coluna para data com horas e depois separar em duas colunas, uma somente com data/mês/ano (no formato date) e outra somente com horas (formato date). Tentei o seguinte comando para mudar o formato:

```
dados <- strptime(dados$data, format = "%d de %b de %Y %H:%M")

## Não funcionou
```

Outra ideia que tive foi antes de fazer a conversão para Date, dividir a coluna em duas, uma com a data (nome data) e outra somente com as horas (nome hora).

```
## Dividi a tabela anterior em uma nova com 3 colunas:

data(character) hora(character)   obs (numeric)
1 de Jan de 2018     00:00              0
1 de Jan de 2018     00:15              0
1 de Jan de 2018     00:30              1
1 de Jan de 2018     00:45              1
1 de Jan de 2018     01:00              2
1 de Jan de 2018     01:15              3

##Daí, tentei mudar o formato somente da coluna hora com o seguinte comando

Dados <- strptime(Dados$hora, format = "%H:%M")

## Não funcionou e apareceu a mensagem de erro "invalid 'tz' value"
```

Alguma sugestão de qual a forma correta de realizar a conversão de character para date com as características dos dados apresentadas?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Tentou alterar o formato da data antes de ler o arquivo? Algo do tipo `format(Sys.Date(), format = "%Y-%b-%d")`. Outra possibilidade é substituir ` de ` (espaço de espaço) por `-` (hífen) e depois tentar converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

Podes utilizar a função `dmy_hm()` do pacote {lubridate}

Criando um exemplo reprodutível:

```
df <- tibble(
    data = c("1 de Jan de 2018 00:00",
             "1 de Jan de 2018 00:15",
             "1 de Jan de 2018 00:30",
             "1 de Jan de 2018 00:45",
             "1 de Jan de 2018 01:00",
             "1 de Jan de 2018 01:15"),
    obs = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3))
```

Aplicando a função `dmy_hm()`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(data = dmy_hm(data))
```

Resultado:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  data                  obs
  <dttm>              <dbl>
1 2018-01-01 00:00:00     0
2 2018-01-01 00:15:00     0
3 2018-01-01 00:30:00     1
4 2018-01-01 00:45:00     1
5 2018-01-01 01:00:00     2
6 2018-01-01 01:15:00     3
```

Agora você tem a variável no formato `datetime` (dttm)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!